# MVC? patterns for game development?

Tags: architecture, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC-like compartmentalization in games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5372/mvc-like-compartmentalization-in-games)

I am thinking of the best way to structure my project and was thought a MVC style pattern would be appropriate. Would be correct having the model handle the majority and basically being the game engine?

Are there any standardised patterns recommended for simple game development?

Model / Game Engine

- Data: Level Design, Chat feeds, etc
- Game Status: Player status, Enemy status, World Status etc etc.
- Engine: Physics, Collisions, AI

View

- 3D: Gameplay, Camera, Rendering...
- 2D: UI etc

Controller:

- Player Input
- UI Input

Comment: (Or like, any of the other dozen questions about how to apply MVC / what the asker thinks is MVC.)